# React Native: Json not showing in Screen: Getting Error in Console

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, react-native

I am getting this error when trying to bring JSON data from mongodb into screen of React Native Application. Screen is showing, just no data. Error is below with code. This is simple hello world app and I am trying to bring in some json data from mongodb to the screen. I am just not sure of the correct setup, though I do have the screen visible up to choose your listing in Listings.js file. for some reason the network is not working. Not sure if I need to proxy in package.json?

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Listings} from './src/Listings';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Air BNB Data Screen</Text>
        <View style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'blue'}}>
          <Listings></Listings>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

src
 Listings.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export class Listings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      show: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const options = {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    };
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8080/api/Listings/10006546', options)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          data: [],
        });
        console.log(data)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  renderRow = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View containerStyle={{ elevation: 1, borderRadius: 15 }}>
          <View row>
              <View flex={2}>
                  <Text h4>{item._id}</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
      </View>
    )
}
render() {

  return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text h3 style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>Choose your Listing!</Text>
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 10 }}
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={this.renderRow}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item._id}
                />
            </View>
        </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 5,
  },
});
```

Error in console - This is the error that I am receiving in the console.

```
Error: Network Error at createError (C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16)
        at EventTarget.handleError (C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:83)
        at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818)
        at EventTarget.setReadyState (C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:575)
        at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:389)
        at C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:502
        at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189)
        at MessageQueue.__callFunction (C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425)
        at C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112
        at MessageQueue.__guard (C:\Users\dr460\reactnativeprojects\FirstApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solve for this was fairly simplistic. I ended up doing some searching, but I was able to find a fix. Instead of using localhost, I was able to use 10.0.2.2 instead. This fixed the network error, however, I do have a data is not defined error now.